# Adding and removing machine from domain, whats happening?

Tags: active-directory, hostname, deployment

I am curious if anybody could breakdown the story of what happens if you were to deploy an image to a machine by some method, add it to domain, and then format the drive and deploy an image again, and then add it to domain with same name.

Would you have to find the machine in the directory and remove it manually? Do you need to leave the domain from the computer before you apply an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to go into ADUC and remove it manually, it will fail if you try to enter it a second time. You will receive the message **A machine account for [computer name] already exists.**